# Prevent user clicking outside Custom lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, controller, lookup

I have a parent custom Lightning Component which includes a custom lookup component inside, for Account Edit/Create. I want when the user starts typing (and results start to appear in a drop-down list) to not let the user leave the child component unless he chooses a valid value, or unless the search text is blank . I tried to use onblur but doesn't seem to work for the dropdown list. Here is the piece of js code that I use and think an extra command or something should be added:

```
searchField : function(component, event, helper) {
    var currentText = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    var resultBox = component.find('resultBox');
    component.set("v.LoadingText", true);
    //06/09/2019: George Galaios: if length of text typed by user >0 show resultBox, else not show it
    if(currentText.length > 0) {
        $A.util.addClass(resultBox, 'slds-is-open');
    }
    else {
        $A.util.removeClass(resultBox, 'slds-is-open');
    }
    //06/09/2019: George Galaios: Call Apex Class to return the results while user is typing
    var action = component.get("c.getResults");
    action.setParams({
        "ObjectName" : component.get("v.objectName"),
        "fieldName" : component.get("v.fieldName"),
        "value" : currentText
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var STATE = response.getState();
        if(STATE === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.searchRecords", response.getReturnValue());
            if(component.get("v.searchRecords").length == 0) {
                console.log('000000');
            }
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
        component.set("v.LoadingText", false);
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `onmouseleave` Event on the wrapping Div of the Custom Lookup.

```
<div onmouseleave="{!c.onLeave}"
```

And inside the event you can check for the selected value, if undefined show info message and keep the list open.

```
onLeave: function(component,event,helper){       
    var selRec = component.get(“v.selectedRecord”); 
    //If undefined show some message and keep the list open
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Saroj.

Comment: Are you able to solve the issue? Is it working?

Comment: Hi Saroj, i solve the issue by using "onmousedown" which executes before onfocusout. Thank you!